# why does the for loop not move to the second item in the list

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a nested loop that works as it should on the first item in the list but then finishes
not sure why it doesn't move the second item?.

```
serials =['BHT350018400', 'BHTM0016380']
url_latency = 'https://my_company/ui/index.html#'
file_system_start_string = '/filesystems/unif/'
file_system_end_string = '__FILESYSTEM__fs_'
section = 'performance'
count = 1
file_system_count = (str(count))

for serial in serials:
    for file in serial:
        while count < 5:
            full_url = url_latency + file_system_start_string + serial + file_system_end_string + file_system_count + '/' + section
            driver.get(full_url)
            driver.maximize_window()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="shell-plugin-area"]/div/div/div/div[2]/ciq-tab-panel/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ciq-performance-details/div/div[1]')))
            screenShot_path =  "\screengrab" + file_system_count + ".png"
            screenshot = driver.save_screenshot(file_path +  screenShot_path)
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            file_system_count = (str(count))
            print(full_url)
```

Comment: Your inner loop is looping through the characters in each string B, H, T etc. Is that the intended behavior? What is the nested loop supposed to iterate through?

Comment: Also you don't reset `count` which is why it wouldn't do anything the second time around

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the 'count' variable
Like this, for example:

```
serials =['BHT350018400', 'BHTM0016380']
url_latency = 'https://my_company/ui/index.html#'
file_system_start_string = '/filesystems/unif/'
file_system_end_string = '__FILESYSTEM__fs_'
section = 'performance'
count = 1
file_system_count = (str(count))

for serial in serials:
    for file in serial:
        count=1 # <------------ here
        while count < 5:
            full_url = url_latency + file_system_start_string + serial + file_system_end_string + file_system_count + '/' + section
            driver.get(full_url)
            driver.maximize_window()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="shell-plugin-area"]/div/div/div/div[2]/ciq-tab-panel/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ciq-performance-details/div/div[1]')))
            screenShot_path =  "\screengrab" + file_system_count + ".png"
            screenshot = driver.save_screenshot(file_path +  screenShot_path)
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1
            file_system_count = (str(count))
            print(full_url)
```

Or anywhere else, depends on program logic

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I hadn't intended on looping through each character, the loop was building a URL, I actually didn't need the inner loop, it works as intended now